# Can we automate to launch apps downloaded from app store using shell script in real iPhone device?

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, automation, ui-automation

Can we automate to launch apps downloaded from app store using shell script in real iPhone device? The bundle ids for app is known but app is not owned by me.

I am trying to use following command to launch app downloaded from app store and was able to get bundle id from google.
running command this in terminal
idevicedebug -u "udid" run "com.apple.calculator"

This does launch app but exit after with error:
ERROR: failed to get the task for process 1063

Is there any way to have it working? This is for simulating running launch and run apps in background in automation while my main app is also running in background.